# Excel Suggestion Similar to functionality when you type =formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of values which i want to populate as the user writes in an excel cell.

I have been trying to replicate an excel feature.

When we type =formula in excel, it shows a dropdown and the list changes as u type in more characters. I want to use a feature like that.

Till now i've tried different methods:

1. Data validation: The problem here is that i can make the drop down get the substring but i have to click on the arrow to see the values. This makes data entry tedious.
2. I tried using combo box: The problem is that i have columns A to column H each having different lists and the user can enter n number of rows.
3. I tried placing the values from the list in the rows and hide them: The problem is that it doesnt show the drop down. It shows only exact values as you type ahead. Hence it doesnt work
4. I tried using list box: The problem here is that i was not sure how to get the cell value while the cell is in edit mode so that i can populate the list box with strings from the list that contains the string from that cell.

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Again, post what you have tried to date. As it stands you haven't asked a question that deserves a response.

Comment: Till now i've tried different methods: Data Validation, Combobox, placing values in above rows and hiding them, listbox. the problems i faced in these are mentioned in the question itself

Comment: If you are looking for code (given the VBA tags) then we expect to see what you have tried. If you are looking for a non-VBA solution you should ask this question on SuperUser instead of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks brettdj for your involvement.

I have finally managed to solve this problem.
Macro cannot be run when any cell is in edit mode. hence one cannot get the values that are being typed. Unless one tries to use API. But then using an API is very tricky and we cannot predict what could go wrong.

Solution:

What i've done is, when on a particular cell, i would place a text box on that cell and keep pasting the values in active cell behind. also i would use the value in the text box to populate the values in the list box using instr function.

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is usually called "autocomplete" or "type ahead". You've already listed the tools that Excel provides out of the box.

Another possibility is to enter all desired values at the top of the column and then hide these rows.

Comment: Yes. but i have more than 3000 values in the lists and user can search for anything from that string. eg: he might type in 'america' and the list would show all the values that contains 'america' whether its in the beginning, middle or end